# WSL export returning error while exporting docker-desktop-data

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I am trying to free some space on my C driver by moving Docker For Desktop images and data to another driver. I've found out, that due to me using wsl2 compability I cannot simply move directory through settings->advanced, and I need to do this by exporting docker-desktop-data image to another drive and then importing it again. It's supposed to be as simple as

```
wsl --export docker-desktop-data place_of_delivery/file.tar
```

But when I'am trying to run this command I am getting error:

```
Exporting the distribution failed.
: tar format cannot archive socket: tar format cannot archive socket: tar format cannot archive socket: tar format cannot archive socketbsdtar: (null)
```

I was also trying with different combinations of path, file formats etc, but it's always returning error

Those are my containers running on wsl:

```
 wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  kali-linux             Stopped         2
```

Also I cannot find any similar case, so does anybody know how can I resolve this?

Comment: Which WSL version? Is WSL shutdown before the export with the command `wsl --shutdown`?

Comment: Yes, it's shutdown. WSL 2

Comment: Try: (1) Log into WSL and delete all files in the `/tmp` folder. (2) Temporarily disabling Windows runtime security.